# Wordpress custom loop displays posts based on the day...is posssible?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I would create a custom loop in the home page that will display only the posts that contains a specific word in its custom field.I'l try to explain it with an example.
EX. I got a website of a Basketball team and 2 custom post types called "COACh" and "TRAINING".
In "COACH" i add the coach and its skills.
In "TRAINING" i add the exrcise's name,the description and in the custom meta box i add the time,the coach,the duration and the day of the execution.
Now,suppose that it's Monday i would display all the TRAININGS that contains the day Monday in its custom field.
Is it possible without a plugin like event calendar????

**IS IT RIGHT?**

```
$today = date("l");
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'palinsesto', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$palinsesto = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ( $training as $post ) {
               $day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'giorno ' ); // here day is key
            if($day==$today)
            while ($post->have_posts()) : $post->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one is the solution for my question...it works great

```
$today = strftime('%A'); 
$day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'giorno ' );
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'palinsesto',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                              array(
                                                    'key' => 'giorno',
                                                    'meta-value' => $value,
                                                    'value' => $today,
                                                    'compare' => '=',
                                                    ))));
if (have_posts()) :
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, I coded below roughly:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'TRAINING', 'posts_per_page' => -1); 
$training = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $training as $post ) {
          $day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'day ' ); // here day is key
          if($day=='Monday')
            echo $post->post_title.'<br />';
            echo $post->post_content.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: `$today = date("l");` change the `if` condition as `if($day==$today)`

Comment: so how will be the loop with the setlocate()?I'm so sorry but i'm a novice i hope can you understand me

Comment: it will be something like this?
`$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=palinsesto');
          setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ita', 'it_IT');
          $today = date("l");
          $day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'giorno ' );
          if ($day==$today) {
              while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>`

Comment: Yes, you can use `WP_QUERY` too. `Date()` returns the server local time. These are clues and way of your solution.

Comment: no it is not correct, `while` is loop and `foreach` is also loop. You wrote loop under loop what is wrong. Just change these line: `if($day==$todat)
            echo $post->post_title.'<br />';
            echo $post->post_content.'<br />';`

Comment: i don't know why it don't works...if u want i can upload all the code on pastebin